# Android WebView cache mechanism

Tags: android, caching, webview

Is Android `WebView` cache and loading mechanism **device-dependent**?

For example, the device is connected to the network, now a webview loads a page(for example, webView.load("http://google.com")), suppose we loaded it before and the content is not expired yet (should be in the cache, right?), will the `webview` loads it from the cache, or access the network again?

When I using some Android apps (which have an embedded browser, i.e., `WebView`), it seems to me that it accesses the network the second time...

I know in an offline mode, the second time loading a same page may retrieve its content from the cache (`LOAD_DEFAULT` and `LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK`), but what about online?